# Rewriting and redirecting URL with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

First time doing the URL rewrite using .htaccess using XAMPP and seen other post here somewhere similar. This post provide me enough ideas [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php) but for some reason my attempt failed.

Starting from the conf setup,  activating  `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` and `AllowOverride All` all instance.

Establishing the requirements such as:

1. redirect all subfolders request to `404.php` which is setting in the root folder.
2. rewrite url for example `http://localhost/mysite/sales.php?a=new&id=0` to `http://localhost/mysite/sales/new/0` or  `http://localhost/mysite/sales.php?a=open&id=456` to  `http://localhost/mysite/sales/open/456`

The `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

   #position at the end !
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ 404.php [L]       #redirect to 404 page and terminate the process


 #For item 2 solution 
 RewriteRule ^mysite/sales/([A-Za-z0-9-\.]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\.]+)/?$ sales.php?a=$1&id=$2  [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: And what is your actual question?

Comment: "redirect all subfolders request to 404.php" - So, a request for any physical subdirectory should trigger a 404? (As opposed to a 301 or 403?) What URL(s) are you currently linking to?

Comment: I thought it was good idea to use a single page (404) when the website received an error request ie directory listing, file listing, etc. Thanks for the comment